# Make TextView and EditText appear when selecting a Radio button?

Tags: java, android, adt

So, on this app I am making, I have a radio group set up, and what I want to do is make a Textview and an EditText appear under the radio group when it when one of the radio buttons are selected. How would I go about making that happen?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Set the visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) of the `View`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setOnCheckedChangeListener method

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        //make TextView & Edit Text visible
                    } else {
                        //Hide the TextView and EditText
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Cool. I wasn't sure whether to use cases or do the setOnCheckedChangeListener. Thank you very much!